# What is the point of Serializable interface?

Tags: scala, serializable, case-class

Here is a [runnable demo](http://scastie.org/13330)

```
import java.io._

object Main extends App {
    case class Value(s: String)
    val serializer = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())
    serializer.writeObject(Value("123"))
    println("success")                        //> success

}
```

Please note that program succeeds despite I do not mark my class with Serializable. Does Serializable make sense in Scala?

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case classes** extend `Serializable` by default in Scala. If you create a regular class it will need to extend `Serializable` otherwise it will throw a serialization error.